# Bounded 0/1-knapsack with dependency constraints without limit

Tags: graph-algorithms

Consider a set of items, weighted with real numbers / costs. You are supposed to select a subset maximizing the sum of the weights of the selected items. But the following contraints must be observed: Every item can be selected only once. Some items have depedencies: If you select item 1, you also have to select item 2 and item 3. Note: Therefore, it's possible to have items with the following property: You **must** select item 1, if you select item 2 or item 3 (imagine a dependency graph) and there is **no limit**: You can select as many items as you want. Last, fragments of items (like 0.7 times item 1) are not allowed.

I ask for an algorithm or some ideas to this problem.

Comment: Input already can be exponential (like $n^{O (n) }$), so the brute force algorithm is not very bad and without having extra information  (e.g on dependencies), it's not possible to hope for even good approximations.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known under the names *"precedence constrained knapsack problem"* and/or *"partially ordered knapsack problem"*. Google will lead you to references to many research papers from the last 40 years, as for instance:

> JOHNSON, D. S., and NIEMI, K. A., On Knapsacks, Partitions, and a New
>   Dynamic Programming Technique for Trees, Mathematics of Operations
>   Research, Vol. 8, pp. 1–14, 1983.

Comment: That helped me, but what about the knapsack problem _without limiting the knapsacks capacity_? The classical one can be solved easily by an greedy algorithm, if the capacity limit is removed, that's a big difference.